# Rails has_many relationship is weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure if anyone has noticed this before because I couldn't find any topic on this issue. But assuming you have a Product model and a Cart model that sets `has_many :products`. and the Product model sets `belongs_to :cart`, the weird thing happens when you set a product instance's `cart_id` (which is the foreign key that refers to the id of the associated cart) to `nil`. Three things can happen:

1. If you already retrieved the associated cart BEFORE setting the associated product's `cart_id` to `nil`, when you destroy that cart instance using its instance method `destroy()`, the associated product **gets destroyed as well**.
2. If you retrieve the associated cart AFTER setting the associated product's `cart_id` to `nil`, when you destroy it using its instance method `destroy`, the associated product **DOES NOT get destroyed**.
3. If you nullify the `cart_id` of the associated product and call the CLASS METHOD `destroy` on  Cart (`Cart.destroy(cart_id)`), the associated product **DOES NOT get destroyed**

I'm pretty sure this has sth to do with the implementation of `has_many`. Probably the state of the relationship gets hardwired to a model instance when you retrieve it. **See the code below:**

Here's the sample code I used to test the above (assuming you already have the 2 above-mentioned model tables)

```
Cart.create   # Assume this one has an id of 1
Product.create(cart_id: 1)
cart=Cart.find(1) # Retrieve the cart before
Product.find(1).update_attribute!(cart_id: nil)
cart.destroy
Product.find_by_id(1)   # nil; the associated product was destroyed
```

---

```
Cart.create # Assume this one has an id of 1
Product.create(cart_id: 1)
Product.find(1).update_attribute!(cart_id: nil)
cart=Cart.find(1) # Retrieve the cart AFTER
cart.destroy
Product.find_by_id(1) # [<Product id:1 cart_id:1 ....>], the assoc product WAS NOT destroyed
```

---

```
Cart.create # Assume this one has an id of 1
Product.create(cart_id: 1)
Product.find(1).update_attribute!(cart_id: nil)
Cart.destroy(1)
Product.find_by_id(1) # [<Product id:1 cart_id:1 ....>], the assoc product WAS NOT destroyed
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the cause of the "strange behavior" is that, by downloading the database object also gets its dependencies. Apparently, even though the database dependency does not exist bargain that removes the owner removes the subordinate elements (and those that already are not).

Therefore, re-download an entry does not destroy the association.

Ale problem, który pokazałeś jest warty odnotowania i sam pewnie bym wpadł w jego pułapkę.

Comment: That's what I said in the post too. I'd love find out more about what's going on behind the curtain, but I don't think I'm good enough to read the source code lol.

Comment: Sorry, I little buzz. Saturday, U know ;)

Comment: This might be due to something similar to Controlling Caching: somehow when you retrieve the Cart, the associated Product objects are retrieved and cached (or somehow "recorded") and the next time they are asked for through the call to Cart#products, they are simply retrieved from the cache

Comment: Simply an object is created that holds all data (including cart_id) and are used when removing the id and not the objects (Delecta FROM carts WHERE id =?).